# 3-digit chopping arithmetic

Tags: numerical-methods

I have to solve the  following system of equations:

$$3.3330x_1 + 15920x_2 + 10.333x_3 = 7953$$
$$2.2220x_1 + 16.710x_2 + 9.6120x_3 = 0.965$$
$$−1.5611x_1 + 5.1792x_2 − 1.6855x_3 = 2.714$$
should I chop off the numbers at the beginning like $$3.3330 \rightarrow 3.33$$ to make a new system   or while performing Gauss elimination

Comment: Why would you want to deliberately make your system inaccurate when it doesn't really make it any easier to solve?

Comment: because i should perform 3-digit chopping

Comment: Is this 3 significant digits or 3 digits after the decimal dot? AFAIR I have seen "chopping" used in both meanings.

Comment: You shoud get something like $(1,\frac12,-1)$ in the end, see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B3.3330%2C15920%2C10.333%7D%2C%7B2.2220%2C16.710%2C9.6120%7D%2C%7B%E2%88%921.5611%2C5.1792%2C%E2%88%921.6855%7D%7D%5E%28-1%29.%7B%7B7953%7D%2C%7B0.965%7D%2C%7B2.714%7D%7D).

Comment: @LutzLehmann , i should write the number 0.something * 10 power d,
so should i perform chopping at the beginning  to the system

Comment: I would say yes, the spirit seems to be that number storage is with 3 digits and the exponent, so reading the input will chop the input numbers. It can be assumed that the "calculation engine" has enough digits to carry out a full multiplication, and then when storing the result the chopping is again applied?